how to create multiple separate files with crunch?
if possible to create alphanumeric word-list with crunch in uppercase with separate files of 10 MB per file
and thank you
here is the example i want to do for my word-list
EXAMPLE 1: AHT9KACNB6T
EXAMPLE 2: 321AFLY5BR1


I can't find the solution to create multiple separate files


This is a fools errand.
I've not used crunch before, so there are likely slightly better ways to call it which I could not make work, but the below should work (I only tried it with 5 characters) -
  crunch 11 11 "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789" | split -a 13 -d -C 10M - op-

This will take the output of crunch, pipe it to split which will split it on line boundaries to no more then 10 megabyte files, reading from STDIN and creating files with the prefix "op-"
Note that this will create an awful lot of combinations -  appprox 150,629,086,123 x 10 meg files full.   I don't have 1402 Petabytes of space anywhere, nor the time or inclination to wait this long to actually test this.  You will need to make sure your filesystem can handle the number of files.   Of-course, relative to the cost of the storage (hundreds of millions to billions of dollars) the cost of getting someone who knows what they are doing to help you with this is a rounding error.  In reality, anything doing this kind of crunching will likely shard the data and avoid storing the permutations (which can trivially be created on demand).

Thank you for your help, I really appreciate your work but I am just a beginner in cybersecurity and just want to test the tools to develop my skills.
